# How do I use OpenVPN as an appliance in Azure to access protected resources?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, azure

I've been successful in creating a Virtual Network, adding subnets and security groups to different levels of our infrastructure, and installing OpenVPN on a VM and establishing a connection to it (even giving myself a static IP). Unfortunately, this is where my knowledge ends.

### Goal

- For my client, I'm interested in "pulling" in multiple subnets so I can access our servers (API Gateway management GUI, database server, etc. ) through a VPN connection.
- For clients I will add in the future (our support team), I am interested in giving them access to only one azure subnet, which will sequester our back office application. I do not want this endpoint exposed to the public internet and I don't want to manually add everyone's IP Addresses at home, grandma's house, etc. A VPN seems correct.

### Things I've Tried

- I only somewhat understand how User Defined Routes work in Azure, especially as they relate to my use case.
- I have been able to enable IP Forwarding for my VM running OpenVPN.
- I've created a dedicated OpenVPN client config file for me.

### Notes

- I'm not using the built-in Point 2 Site Gateway in Azure because it does not support OSX and I would rather not force myself and everyone else to run Parallels.
- I've also used [this guide](https://techlib.barracuda.com/NG61/ConfigAzureDefaultGateway) to help me along some even though `Firewall !== VPN Server`. I'm not quite connecting the dots though.

**EDIT**: Not sure if this makes a difference, but let's go ahead and assume I'll switch from OpenVPN to OpenVPN Access Server in the near future.

Comment: I'm not sure yet what is the question.